# Make table show percentages instead of frequencies in R

Tags: r, function

I have some words in my dataframe `df` each belonging to category A or B. Within each category  the words may be of type 1, 2 or 3. I used the `table()` function to show how the words are distributed across the categories and types. The output looks like:

```
         category
type     A    B
1        30  79
2        12  94
3        29  6
```

As you can see the table counts frequencies, but I want it to calculate the percentages instead. I have tried `prop.table` but I get the following error

> Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables

I couldn't find a solution anywhere else; please help. Thank you.

Here's my sample data:

```
head(items)

       item   type category
[1]    PA100   1    A
[2]    PB101   2    A
[3]    UR360   2    A
[4]    PX977   3    B
[5]    GA008   3    B
[6]    GR446   3    A
```

Comment: See `?prop.table`. Also have a look on SO - [this for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866488/is-it-possible-to-add-percentages-to-a-contingency-table) [and this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578741/r-compute-percentage-values-in-data-frame)

Comment: @RichardScriven percentages of each type in each category instead of frequency, e.g in the top left cell instead of 30 it should be 42.25 since 30 is 42.25 percent of the total of column A

Comment: @thelatemail @user20650 i have tried `prop.table` but i get the following error `Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables`

Comment: Then it would be best to provide a small sample of the data.

Comment: @maryam - are you applying `prop.table` to your table, or your original `df` dataframe? - you want to do the former - try this: `mytab <- table(df$type,df$category); prop.table(mytab,2);`

Comment: @maryam Read the error message. It says your data frame must have all numeric variables. Does it have all numeric variables? If not, make them numeric or drop the non-numeric ones, and try again.

Comment: @RichardScriven there

Comment: @thelatemail okay thanks may I please ask what the `2` in `prop.table(mytab,2)` does?

Comment: @maryam - it's the margin.  1 means across the rows, 2 means over the columns, NULL means the whole table.  That's actually in my answer.

Comment: @RichardScriven ohhh all clear now thank yooooooouuuu!!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use a `prop.table` on a `table` object.  In your case, use a `margin = 1`, which means we want to calculate the percentages across the rows of the table.

```
> tab <- with(items, table(type, category))
> prop.table(tab, margin = 1)
#     category
# type         A         B
#    1 1.0000000 0.0000000
#    2 1.0000000 0.0000000
#    3 0.3333333 0.6666667
```

For actual percentages, you can multiply the table by 100

```
> prop.table(tab, 1)*100
#     category
# type         A         B
#    1 100.00000   0.00000
#    2 100.00000   0.00000
#    3  33.33333  66.66667
```

where

```
items <- 
structure(list(item = structure(c(3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("GA008", 
"GR446", "PA100", "PB101", "PX977", "UR360"), class = "factor"), 
    type = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), category = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("item", 
"type", "category"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: thanks do you know how I can multiply by 100 so I get percentages instead of fractions? sorry!

Answer (score 2):

This might be quite late but sharing it in case someone else faces a similar problem. You can still achieve your required output with `table()` and `prop.table()`. You just have to do it in two steps for factor variables.

```
df = table(items$type, items$category)
prop.table(df)
```

Read below for further explanation.

For the following dataframe `items`:

```
 item type category
PA100  1        A
PB101  2        A
UR360  2        A
PX977  3        B
GA008  3        B
GR446  3        A
```

First, run the `table()` command and store it into `df`

```
df = table(items$type, items$category)

df

A  B
1  0
2  0
1  2
```

Then, run your `prop.table()` command on `df` as below:

```
prop.table(df)

A         B
0.1666667 0.0000000
0.3333333 0.0000000
0.1666667 0.3333333
```

With the `round()` command you can also specify the number of decimal places you want to keep:

```
round(prop.table(df),digits = 2)

A     B
0.17  0.00
0.33  0.00
0.17  0.33
```

And if you wanted to keep the percentages only, you could do the following:

```
round(100*prop.table(df),digits = 0)

A   B
17  0
33  0
17  33
```